# Preview markdown in VS code in browser

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, github-flavored-markdown

I am writing some github markdown with VS Code and while it has a preview, I would like to view it in my default Chrome browser so I can debug my css settings with inspect - however without checking it into github and browsing there (which slows things down a lot).

As far as I can tell from the docs [VS Code Markdown Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview), the markdown preview window has no such debugging capabilities.

Is there anyway to get the markdown preview to display in the default browser instead of its own preview window.

Answer (score 1):

According to VS Code's documentation [Extending the Markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_extending-the-markdown-preview), defining the *CSS* under *VS Code*'s *Workspace Settings* should show the correct output in *VS Code*'s preview.

> ```
> // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
> {
>     "markdown.styles": [
>         "Style.css"
>     ]
> }
> ```